# how to take next element with specific class

Tags: jquery

I'm making simple slider, and i have a problem with removing class of previous item. I need to remove class active from previous ".modal-body img". How can i do it correctly? Right now its not switching to next image.
Any other suggestion on code improving is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" ><img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png" alt="" ></a>

                    <div class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/portfolio_1.png" alt="">
                        <span class="arrow prev"></span>
                        <span class="arrow next"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img src="images/portfolio/office_2.jpg" alt="" ></a>

                    <div class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/office_2.jpg" alt="" >
                        <span class="arrow prev"></span>
                        <span class="arrow next"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img src="images/portfolio/office_3.jpeg" alt="" ></a>

                    <div class="modal fade"arial-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="images/portfolio/office_3.jpeg" alt="" >
                        <span class="arrow prev"></span>
                        <span class="arrow next"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
    var next = $(".next");
    var prev = $(".prev");
    var item = $('.modal-body > img');
    item.first().addClass("active");

    next.click(function(){
        var index = item.filter(".active").index();
        item.eq(index+1).addClass("active").item(index).removeClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: `$("next");` needs to be `$(".next");` and `$("prev");` needs to be `$(".prev");`

Comment: oh right i forgot to add, but still i have mistake in this line  item.eq(index+1).addClass("active").item(index).removeClass("active");

Comment: `item.eq(index+1)` will give you one item, if you then do `.item(index)` on it  it won't give you anything, use:  `item.eq(index+1).addClass("active"); item(index).removeClass(‌​"active");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
next.click(function(){
        var item = $('.modal-body > img');
        var index = +$('.modal-body > img').index($('.modal-body > img.active'));
        index = (item.length - 1 === index) ? 0 : index + 1;
        item.removeClass('active');
        item.eq(index).addClass("active");
    });
```

First we get the index by finding the active element. Then, we check the corner condition when the index is at the element. We can remove class active from all items and add only on desired item.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgeMrw when i click on blue next button, the red transferes to the next image. what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: class is switching to next modal when clicking button, but images is not switching to next one, what i'm missing in my code?